# r ggplot2 How to make vjust in geom_text put label at bottom of bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to solve two problems:

1. The first is to let some bars in a bar graph go beyond the top of a
   graph.
2. The second is to insert the value of the bar at the bottom
   of the graph, so the person looking at the graph can tell just how
   far above the graph the bar goes.

The code below is my attempt to solve both of these. It solves the first with `coord_cartesian`, in the sense that a bar runs off the top of the graph. But it doesn't solve the second. The values of the bar are at the top of the bar rather than at the bottom. I thought vjust = "bottom" or 0 would do the trick, but I've tried it in a variety of places without success.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(
  scenario = c("2010", "SSP2-NoCC", "SSP2-HGEM", "SSP1-NoCC", "SSP3-NoCC", "2010", "SSP2-NoCC", "SSP2-HGEM", "SSP1-NoCC", "SSP3-NoCC", "2010", "SSP2-NoCC", "SSP2-HGEM", "SSP1-NoCC", "SSP3-NoCC", "2010", "SSP2-NoCC", "SSP2-HGEM", "SSP1-NoCC", "SSP3-NoCC"),
  value = c(45.75, 15.74, 17.16, 10.73, 24.03, 15.37, 6.87, 7.61, 5.63, 8.87, 9, 3.43, 3.76, 2.93, 4.01, 2.53, 1.79, 1.95, 1.77, 1.79),
  region_name = c("Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Low", "Lower middle", "Lower middle", "Lower middle", "Lower middle", "Lower middle", "Upper middle", "Upper middle", "Upper middle", "Upper middle", "Upper middle", "High", "High", "High", "High", "High")
)

yLab <- "(percent)"
yRange <- c(0, 40)
plotTitle <-"Food Budget Share Of Per Capita Income"
colorList <- c("#000000", "#FEF0D9", "#2CA25F", "#FC8D59", "#D7301F")


ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = factor(region_name), y = value, group = scenario)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = scenario), position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = yRange) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = yLab) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, family = "Times", face = "plain")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Times", face = "plain")) +
  geom_text(aes(label = value, vjust = "bottom"), position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3, angle = 90,  color = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorList) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11, family = "Times", face = "plain")) +
  ggtitle(plotTitle)
```

[image]

Comment: Try `geom_text(aes(label = value, y=0.1), position = position_dodge(0.9), 
            size = 3, color = "white", vjust=0) +`. `y=0.1` places the text at the bottom of the bar. `vjust=0` bottom justifies the text, meaning that the bottom of the text is placed at `y=0.1`. You can also do `label=round(value, 1)` if you want the value labels to have fewer digits.

Answer (score 11):

The trick to your second problem is to map the `y` aesthetic to a fixed value. I used `y = 1.25` but you can adjust as you please. I also used `size = 2.25` because it looks better, in my opinion. And instead of `vjust = 'bottom'`, use `hjust = 'left'` because you are applying these settings at a 90 degree rotation. So the `geom_text` portion should be

```r
geom_text(data = dt,
          aes(x = factor(region_name), y = 0.5, label = round(value, 1)),
          position = position_dodge(0.9),
          size = 2.25, angle = 90,
          color = "white", hjust = 'left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**Set Plot Limits and Allow bar to extend beyond**

You can use `coord_cartesian` to set the limits of the plot. Unlike `scale_y_continuous`, this lets data expand beyond the plot limits. So `coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 30))`

**Label Bar**

Similar to the other answer, but you can use an `ifelse` statement within the `geom_text` to only display the label in bars which are big enough for the label to fit.

**Example Code**

```
ggplot(data = dt, aes(x = factor(region_name), y = value, group = scenario)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = scenario), position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 30)) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = yLab) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1, family = "Times", face = "plain")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(family = "Times", face = "plain")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = colorList) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 11, family = "Times", face = "plain")) +
  ggtitle(plotTitle) +
  geom_text(data = dt, aes(x = factor(region_name),
                           y=0.5, label = ifelse(value < 3, "", round(value, 1))),
            position = position_dodge(0.9),
            size = 2.25,
            angle = 90,
            color = "white",
            hjust = 'left')
```

[image]